# Include DataTables search box and Show entries in the _NavBar

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC and I searched this topic but couldn't understand how to make what i want works I feel like it is something very simple. I want to include the search box and Show entries in the Navbar not underneath it.Thank you and sorry for my simple question.
[This is the output I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdAuH.png)

This is my _NavBar.chtml class:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            @Html.ActionLink("Iventory Tracker", "Index", "Inventory", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })

        </div>
       <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            @*
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Inventory", "Index", "Inventory")</li>

            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            *@
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is My Index view: The JS that displays the dataTables

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#inventories").DataTable({
                "pageLength": 100,




            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Find out the css class for Datatable Search functionality. Create another instance with the exact same name as that css class, and add styles that are needed for it be moved to Navbar.

Comment: @Batgirl for some reason I can't find search in the .css for datatables package

Comment: Look for dataTables_filter class, and rewrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to re-locate the select entries and make it fixed:
.

```
dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 99999;
        margin-top: -55px;
        color: azure;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

This is to re-locate the search box and make it fixed:

```
 .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter {
        position: fixed;
        margin-left: 200px;
        z-index: 99999;
        margin-top: -55px;
        color: azure;
    }
```

Insert in the view page where you have the dataTable and it will over ride the original css.